# Android use thread to draw every 4 seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, time, drawing

I am quite new to Android and want to create a simple game.
Therefor i need a thread which is drawing a transparent Rectangle on different positions every 4 seconds with a 2 second break (without drawing).
I got it working with a "recursive" thread calling a new instance of itself with handler.postdelayed.
My feeling about threads tells me, that this isn't a very nice way...
While searching here for similar topics, i found out about the Timer construct. Can i use this for my problem?
Is there a better way to do this?

(edit)  The thread is meant for highlighting part of the gameboard, but only for 4 seconds. After that there should be 2 seconds without highlighting. Then 4 seconds highlighting the next part of the board etc.

(edit2) I couldn't use sleep, because it froze my UI. If anyone has a similar situation, here is how i solved it:

```
public class myRunnable implements Runnable {

private int duration;
private int counter;
private boolean highlight;


public myRunnable(int duration, boolean highlight) {
    this.duration = duration;
    this.highlight = !highlight;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    if (highlight) {
        // highlight 4s long
        highlight();
        invalidate();
            myThread = new myRunnable(duration, highlight);
            postDelayed(myThread, duration);

    } else {
        // pause (2s)
        resetHighlight();
        invalidate();
            myThread = new myRunnable(duration, highlight);
            postDelayed(myThread, noHighlightDuration);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `every 4 seconds with a 2 second break (without drawing).` ?? can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this is use to use **invalidate()** to call the **onDraw()** function and a method to update the position. Something like this-

```
  int x,y;
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  x=10;
  y=10;
  canvas.drawRect(___);
  update();
  invalidate();
  }

  private void update() 
  {/*Change the x and y/*}
```

Here everytime **inavlidate()** is called from anywhere the **onDraw()** is called again with the new x and y.

Comment: thx, i do know how to use onDraw/invalidate. The point of my question is, how to do this scheduled like this: 4s highlight, 2 seconds no highlight, 4s highlight another part, etc.

Comment: use 'try {  
         Thread.sleep(30);  
      } catch (InterruptedException e) { }' 30 is in millisecond.

Comment: Why would i use 30 ms?
Anyway i tried Thread.sleep() with different durations and my UI gets frozen until this dialog pops up: "MyApplication is not responding"